# Processing html mail using phpmailer mail->Body fetching mail body using imap_fetchbody

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Okay. So what i did was that i retrieved the body of an email using imap_fetchbody and forward the contents in it to another user's email using mail->Body.

The following are the 2 different formats of the mail i get from different settings:

eg1: 
mail->isHtml(true);
[image]

eg2: 
mail->isHtml(false);
[image]

The result i want to have is eg2 but i need to insert html code into the mail itself hence i cannot have mail->isHtml(false), i need it to be true. I'm not sure why this is happening but i realize that the cause in difference in formatting is due to this mail->isHtm() property.

What can i do?

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.